# Get entries after a certain time

Tags: search, entry, datetime, query

I am trying to get all entries from my events section in Craft 3 that occur after 17:00.

My current code is:
`{% set events = craft.entries.section('events').eventStartTime('>= ' ~ '17:00'|time ).all() %}`

The `>=` is being ignored as far as I can tell. The query just returns all events.

The `eventStartTime` field is a Date/Time field that is set to just show the time (I know that behind the scenes Craft still treats this as a DateTime object but I was hoping that the `|time` filter would help with that.

When I have created similar queries on a DateTime field but looking at the date rather than time, they have worked as expected - maybe I am missing something when it comes to the time portion of the object?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this Craft 2 or 3?

Comment: Ah sorry, Craft 3

Answer (score 2):

That will give you all entries, from today (so not past entries) starting after 5PM:

```twig
{% set startAfterTime = '17.00'|date('U') %}
{% set today = now|atom|date %}

{% set events = craft.entries()
    .section('events')
    .status(['live', 'pending'])
    .postDate('>=' ~ today )
    .eventStartTime('>=' ~ startAfterTime)
    .all() %}
```

Comment: This is pretty much identical to the approach I tried first and unfortunately does not work, I just have all entries returned to me.

Comment: @jaypratt that's really strange, I tested it here as well? Is it just a standard entry Section..?

Comment: Yep - just a channel.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked after I changed the date format into `{% set today = now|date('Y-m-d') %}`, so I think this should work:

```
{% set startAfterTime = '17.00'|date('U') %}
{% set today = now|date('Y-m-d') %}

{% set events = craft.entries()
    .section('events')
    .status(['live', 'pending'])
    .postDate('>=' ~ today )
    .eventStartTime('>=' ~ startAfterTime)
    .all() %}
```